# Array of tuples: return unique values based on weights (Python)

Tags: python, tuples, unique

I have zipped together in Python two arrays

```
w
array([ 0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.75,  1.  ])
index
array([ 218,  218, 1491, 2456, 1491, 1490,  250,  219])

test=zip(w,index)
test
[(0.5, 218), (1.0, 218), (0.5, 1491), (1.0, 2456), (1.0, 1491), (1.0, 1490), (0.75, 250), (1.0, 219)]
```

and I would like to return a new list of tuples, which only contains the unique indices (i.e. "index") which have the highest weights.

In other words, I would like to obtain in this case:

```
test2
[(1.0, 218), (1.0, 2456), (1.0, 1491), (1.0, 1490), (0.75, 250), (1.0, 219)]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {}
# Group the weights based on the indices
for wt, idx in test:
    d.setdefault(idx, []).append(wt)

# Create a new list with the max of weights and the index tuples
print [(max(d[idx]), idx) for idx in d]
# [(1.0, 1490), (1.0, 1491), (1.0, 2456), (0.75, 250), (1.0, 219), (1.0, 218)]
```